# Can zero be used as exception case for MurmurHash3

Tags: hash, guava

In a specific use case in our organisation I have chosen to use MurmurHash3 (128-bit version) to determine whether a record consisting of multiple elements are unique compared to another record. Choice of algorithm and debate regarding the wisdom of using a hash to determine uniqueness aside, can the value zero (0) be used as an exception value for the hash return?

We are currently using Guava's Hashing to generate the hash on a `String` input and  exceptions cannot be used to report an exception on a `null` (which is possible) input. Also, the return value has to be a *primitive* 64-bit value as it is consumed by an external system that I do not have control over so the equivalent of a *null* cannot be used to report on the exception either.

**Note:** Expected range of characters in the input string is in the Basic Latin and Latin-1 unicode blocks. No NUL characters.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one in 2^128 inputs will genuinely hash to 0.

You could create a slightly modified hash function that never returns 0, however -- perhaps if the hash genuinely comes out to zero, it hashes the input concatenated with an arbitrary extra byte, and keeps concatenating until the hash comes out nonzero.

Comment: Better than trying to deterministically produce "an arbitrary byte": Just say "if the hash came out to zero, then return 1 instead." Sure, this makes "1" come up twice as often as "2" or any other number — but the difference is $1/2^{128}$ — 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000588% versus 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000294%. It's astronomically unlikely for _either_ 0 or 1 to be rolled before the heat death of the universe, and the chance that they'd _both_ be rolled is... well, functionally impossible.